# SyntaxError: Invalid syntax in a codecademy program

Tags: python

in the PygLatin 10/11 exercise on the Codecademy Python course, i have to do the following:

> Set new_word equal to the slice from the 1st index all the way to the
>   end of new_word. Use [1:len(new_word)] to do this.

And I receive the following error:

```
File "python", line 9
    new_word = [1:len(new_word)]
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And this is the code:

```
File "python", line 9
    new_word = [1:len(new_word)]
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here you will find screenshots which might be of help:

[image]

This might be a very stupid question, but I really want to understand where I am wrong with this, soIi don't make the same mistake in the future. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: The right hand side of your assignment is wrong. This `[1:len(new_word)]` looks like an attempt at list slicing, but you don't specify any list to slice *from*. It should be something like `some_sequence[1:len(new_word)]`

Comment: the list slicing needs a string to process upon , let the string be `var = "Hello"`, then `var[1:]` would be equal to `ello` but `[1:]` would result in error.

Comment: Please share your code as text ([formatted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) with four spaces at the start of each line). Otherwise someone writing an answer will have to re-type it from the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the code should be:

```
pyg = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a word:')

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    word = original.lower()
    first = word[0]
    new_word = word + first +pyg
    new_word = new_word[1:]
    print new_word
else:
    print 'empty'
```

Let's say the input is *Hello*. This line: `new_word = word + first +pyg` will give you *hellohay* but what you need is *ellohay* so you need to slice the `new_word`in order to lose the first *h* which is `new_word[0]` so, `new_word` should start with *e*, which is `new_word[1]` this is why you need this line: `new_word = new_word[1:]`

The output is:

`ellohay`

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:  `new_word = [1:len(new_word)]`

This is right: `new_word = new_word[1:len(new_word)]`

Another thing, if you want to slice starting from i to the end of your list, you can do:

```
new_word = new_word[1:]
```

Answer (score 1):

You use square brackets for slicing, but you have to specify the thing you are slicing.

Just like you can access specific elements of lists, strings and the like, you can also access sublists and substrings. Like so:

```
a = "this is a long string"
a[0] == "t"
a[0:4] == "this"
a[1:len(a)] == "his is a long string"
```

You're getting the `SyntaxError` because you didn't specify the thing you are slicing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a slice of `new_word`, not a slice of nothing.